# Ionic application Xcode build errors

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have created a new ionic react project based on the templates on the ionic website and also added capacitor ios.
When I open my project and try to run it in Xcode I get the following errors as attached in the image.
Wondering if anyone can help with this.

[image]

Thanks

[image: Error image]

Comment: Please install pod

Comment: No pictures of text please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your Podfile hasn't been updated.

You need to run:

`npx cap update ios`

then:

`npx cap build ios`

This will force refresh the Podfile for you.

If this doesn't work, you should try deleting your iOS folder within your IDE and reinstalling with:

`npx cap add ios` or `ionic cap add ios`

then:

`npx cap build ios` or `ionic cap build ios`.

## Mac with Apple Silicon (M1)

The above is still correct, but there is a bug within CocoaPods which will prevent you from installing it correctly and therefore run these steps first:

`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`

then:

`arch -x86_64 pod install`

This will simulate Intel architecture and allow you to install the pods.

Comment: Hey, 
So I tried running "npx cap update ios" and I get an error. I have attached the image to the main posting

Comment: Actually I've just realised, are you using a Mac with an M1 chip?

Comment: Yeah I have the M1 chip

Comment: I've updated it with an M1 solution